# Server, gui, then uninstalling the gui

Tags: networking

I'm planning to turn my old PowerPC G4 into a wordpress website.  I'd like to use the server edition of ubuntu 10.04, install a GUI (to set up wordpress) then uninstall the gui.

Would I be able to do that?

Comment: you dont need a gui to install wordpress - just follow a good-guide such as this ubuntu-geek blog:  http://www.ubuntugeek.com/installing-wordpress-3-0-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the GUI you want on the server edition by typing:

`sudo apt-get install [xk]ubuntu-desktop`,

where `ubuntu` installs Gnome,
`kubuntu` installs KDE and `xubuntu` installs XFCE.

You can later uninstall it with:

`sudo apt-get remove/purge [xk]ubuntu-desktop`

Personally though, i think that what you're trying to do doesn't need all that fuss.
You should just practice a bit with shell editors like `vi/vim or nano`.

Alternatively, you could try to work remotely on the machine and make all the necessary configuration.

Comment: The reason I want to have a gui for a bit is because I don't want to configure the mysql databases myself, I rather have a browser open and click on the buttons to install it instead.

Comment: I see. But if there's going to be another computer on the same LAN, i would suggest you do all the work from there (remotely). I just like the idea of keeping servers as 'clean' as possible (that is, install only necessary packages). But it's your machine, you know better ;-)

Comment: I agree.  That sounds like a good idea, I kinda forgot ubuntu server had openssh :o

Comment: Good to hear that, i'll add it to my original post. Good luck ;)

Comment: @alexy13 Before running `sudo apt-get install ...` you should run `sudo apt-get update` unless you've done so very recently. This updates information about installable packages and their sources (it doesn't upgrade anything). Also, before installing a GUI on a server, I recommend [reading why you probably shouldn't](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerGUI#Arguments_Against_a_GUI). (Then if you decide to go ahead, that article has some more information about options for GUI's, including some information not currently in this answer.)

Comment: Also, please note that removing/purging a [metapackage](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages) like `ubuntu-desktop` will *not* uninstall the GUI. The way these packages work is to install no files themselves, but pull in all the packages that are part of the GUI as dependencies. Since these dependencies are, at least initially, automatically installed (as dependencies) rather than manually installed, removing or purging the metapackage *and then running `sudo apt-get autoremove`* (or `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove`) will *sometimes* work. And sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Webmin is also a great way to administer your Ubuntu box. Once you have Apache up and running install Webmin.

Can't recall how I did it though.Try Googling Webmin.

Comment: ***Webmin is not supported in ubuntu.*** Ubuntu fully dropped support for it before 10.10. This is because it does not work with the configuration systems as Ubuntu does, so it creates incompatibilities and breakage.

Comment: @LordofTime who said? Im running webmin on ubuntu server 11.04 and 12.04 :)

Comment: @penreturn the server team, which i'm a part of.

Comment: @LordofTime its work perfect on my server unless I install virtualmin. Seriously!