# Which OS would be better for these computers: Ubuntu server or normal Ubuntu?

Tags: server, samba, raspberrypi, domain-server

My network map:

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I am unsure about which Ubuntu OS would suit these tasks better.

For the Primary Domain controller and backup domain controller, I am planning to have Samba file and print server on a normal Ubuntu PC.

And for my Raspberry Pi cluster web server load balancer, the OS will be normal Ubuntu. (By the way, RPi stands for Raspberry Pi).

I have read in multiple tutorials that Samba file and printer share will be better in Ubuntu Server OS, but I don't really get it.

What is the difference between normal Ubuntu and Ubuntu Server, and which OS would be better on these computers in the picture?

Comment: Server or desktop is not a matter of the power of the machine but of the purpose of the machine. If it is a webserver -> server If it is for personal computing -> desktop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu (Desktop) is an Ubuntu Server + GUI. One should always prefer Server edition on a server machine, i.e. a computer without need for user interactions (keyboard + screen) on daily basis.

If you realize you need GUI later, you can install it at any time using [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool):

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Or a lightweight version like [Xubuntu core](http://xubuntu.org/news/introducing-xubuntu-core/):

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-core
```

Or [Lubuntu core](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall):

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-core
```

GUI can be uninstalled later, see [Remove GUI on Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/259544/remove-gui-on-ubuntu-server), [Server, gui, then uninstalling the gui](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57659/server-gui-then-uninstalling-the-gui) or [How to remove desktop environments?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147858/how-to-remove-desktop-environments).

However, I recommend to spend some time on learning how to use [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) with server computers. You can easily search the web for the right commands for most tasks you can imagine with a Linux machine.

Comment: Ah, I see, but if I need to, is there a way to install another light weight GUI?

Comment: Is there a way to uninstall GUI from Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, see updated answer.